# nginx dynamic value from 1 to 1000 in if or map

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to use dynamic value for a variable in NGINX either using if is evil or Map ?

What i need is return 404 if the $variable is less than 1000 !

Maybe something like :

```
if ($variable = 1 To 1000 ) {
return 404;
}
```

Or

```
if ($variable less than 1000 ) {
return 404;
}
```

Or maybe using map ?

```
map $variable $test {

    default                   0;
    "~1 TO 1000"             1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `if` for doing `return`s (as long as it happens outside any `location` directive) is not evil at all.

NGINX does not support `if ($variable < 1000)` arithmetic comparison, but you can replace that with equivalent regular expression. So:

```
server {
    ...
    if ($variable ~ "^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,5})?$") {
        return 404;
    }
```

For explanation of the regular expression used, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411052/regular-expression-for-a-range-0-but-less-than-1000#answer-9411316).

Comment: So what is the right config for my case ?

Comment: @anoflsogodi I put an example in my answer.

Comment: What should i change in you example exactly ?

Comment: nothing :) it's a working config that satisfies your requirement "if an argument's value is less than 1000, then return 404", that's what it does!

Comment: What if i want to change 1000 to 800 maybe what should i change ?

Comment: You then have to construct appropriate regex. There are tools for this you may find online like [this one](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/)